# Showing key values Array Items on Django Template

Tags: python, arrays, django, random

*Hello,
i am relatively new to Python & Django.*

**My Problem:**

```
resp, content = httplib2.Http().request("http://api.xxxxx.com/api/" + username)
str_content = content.decode('utf-8')
user = json.loads(str_content)
```

*i return the user string and try to use that on my template, the json looks like that:*

```
{
    "XXXXXX": {
    "bans": 6,
    "ban_info": {
        "randomrandomrandom": "randomrandomrandom",
        "randomrandom": "randomrandomrandomrandom"
    }
}
```

*how can i rotate through these items and access the random informations?*

**like:**
user['bans'] returns 6

but how do i get these random things?
**user['ban_info']['???'] should return**

---

*My English is not the best, sorry for that.
I hope i described my problem good enough!*

Thanks for every help on that topic, i also hope, that this is not a duplicate!

Comment: What do you mean by "rotate"?

Comment: Ah sorry, i mean... like a each loop. I want to get all these variables, and put them in my view, but how can i access them, i don't know the names... that's my problem

Comment: So it's that you want to get each item (which has random keys and values), not that you want to randomly choose some of them?

Comment: Yeah, completely right. :) Sorry for that misleading description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a for loop?

```
for x in user['ban_info']:
    print x
```

For keys and values:

```
for (k, v) in user['ban_info'].iteritems():
    print k
    print v
```

Comment: Yeah, but now i only get the KEYS, how do i access the values IN X? :)

Comment: Perfect, that's what i need. Just one more thing, how can i use that in my view now? If i try {% for x, y in user.ban_info %} it's not working, if i just use X without Y it works, but i don't have the values then; **GOT IT! Solution: {% for x,y in user.ban_info.items %}**

Comment: That's a template, not a view :)

Comment: _Argh xD. Sorry. But thanks for you help. That was insanely fast. Thank you all so much :)_

Answer (score 2):

[Iterating over a dict returns its keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3294899/3096768), for example:

```
pizza = {"cheese": "mozarella",
         "topping": "pepperoni"}

for key in pizza:
    print pizza[key]

# outputs: mozarella
#          pepperoni
```

In your example you can simply do:

```
for key in user['ban_info']:
    print user['ban_info'][key]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the views.py you should send a response with a dict of objects or in your case, the user object itself, like:

```
HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(user), mimetype='application/json')
```

In your template you can access that dict with Django template tags like:

```
{{user.bans}}
```

Or iterate over a child array like:

```
{% for info in user.ban_info %}
    {{ info }}
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% for key, value in user.ban_info %}
    {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```